# JUnit 5: react on Exception from Extension (Callback)

Tags: java, testing, exception, junit5, junit-jupiter

In my Tests I have several Extensions via the *Callback Implementation.
(`BeforeAllCallback`, `BeforeEachCallback`, ....)

And I want to react on specific Exceptions from the implementation of the Callbacks.
e.g.
The Callback tries to report some teststatus to a TM-Tool.
And I dont want the tests to fail, if the TM-Tool is not available.

So I found the `LifecycleMethodExecutionExceptionHandler` and `TestExecutionExceptionHandler`, but they are not invoked if an exception is thrown by a Lifecylce-Callback.

My TestClass:

```
@ExtendWith(ExceptionExtension.class)
@ExtendWith(MyExtension.class)
public class MyTest {
    private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MyTest.class);

    @BeforeEach
    void setup(){
        LOG.info("called BeforeEach");
        throw new RuntimeException("from BeforeEach");
    }

    @Test
    void test() {
        LOG.info("called Test");
        throw new RuntimeException("from Test");
    }
}
```

The Extension implementing the Callback:

```
public class MyExtension implements BeforeAllCallback {
    private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MyExtension.class);


    @Override
    public void beforeAll(ExtensionContext context) {
        LOG.info("called BeforeEach Extension");
        throw new RuntimeException("from BeforeEach Extension");
    }
}
```

And the Extension Handling the Exceptions:

```
public class ExceptionExtension implements LifecycleMethodExecutionExceptionHandler, TestExecutionExceptionHandler {

    private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ExceptionExtension.class);

    @Override
    public void handleBeforeAllMethodExecutionException(ExtensionContext context, Throwable throwable) throws Throwable {
        LOG.error("Exception handled:" + throwable.getMessage());
        return;
    }

    @Override
    public void handleBeforeEachMethodExecutionException(ExtensionContext context, Throwable throwable) throws Throwable {
        LOG.error("Exception handled:" + throwable.getMessage());
        return;
    }

    @Override
    public void handleAfterEachMethodExecutionException(ExtensionContext context, Throwable throwable) throws Throwable {
        LOG.error("Exception handled:" + throwable.getMessage());
        return;
    }

    @Override
    public void handleAfterAllMethodExecutionException(ExtensionContext context, Throwable throwable) throws Throwable {
        LOG.error("Exception handled:" + throwable.getMessage());
        return;
    }

    @Override
    public void handleTestExecutionException(ExtensionContext context, Throwable throwable) throws Throwable {
        LOG.error("Exception handled:" + throwable.getMessage());
        return;
    }
}
```

The Problem:
When Execution the code as shown above, the Exception from `MyExtension` is not handled by the `LifecycleMethodExecutionExceptionHandler`.

I receive the following output and the tests is aborted:

```
MyExtension - called BeforeEach Extension
```

If `MyExtension` were not to throw an Exception - everything works as expected:

```
MyExtension - called BeforeEach Extension
MyTest - called BeforeEach
ExceptionExtension - Exception handled:from BeforeEach
MyTest - called Test
ExceptionExtension - Exception handled:from Test
```

What am I missing?